# ffmpeg/ffprobe input as buffer stream, get an error always

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, ffprobe

#### Code to reproduce

I attached the test.gif file on https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/assets/122068264/e1f3aa31-5386-4dab-a409-9a224e0610fe

```js
const ffprobeInstaller = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');


(async () => {

    const buffer = fs.readFileSync('test.gif');
    let readableStream = new Readable();
    readableStream._read = () => { };
    readableStream.push(buffer);
    readableStream.push(null);

    // console.log(ffprobe.path, ffprobe.version);
    ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobeInstaller.path);
    let metadata = await get_video_meta_data(readableStream);

    async function get_video_meta_data(stream) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            new ffmpeg()
                .input(stream)
                .ffprobe((err, data) => {
                    // console.log(err);
                });
            resolve();
        });
    }
})();
```

(note: if the problem only happens with some inputs, include a link to such an input file)

#### Expected results

data should include duration but empty.

#### Observed results

data is empty and err happens.
Here is error data:

```
  libavutil      58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavcodec     60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavformat    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavdevice    60.  0.100 / 60.  0.100
  libavfilter     9.  1.100 /  9.  1.100
  libswscale      7.  0.100 /  7.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
pipe:0: Input/output error
```

I only need the metadta for the input gif file. specifically, duration field.